# How to install homestead 1.1.0

Tags: laravel, macos, homestead, php-5.6

I need to work on an old project that uses PHP5.6 , it is a Laravel project. Its developer used vagarant `2.2.2`, Virtualbox  version `5.3.1` and homestead version `1.1.0`, I installed Virtualbox and Vagrant, but I having issues getting this homestead version. I could not find it here https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases?after=v2.0.3, I tried to use another version 2.0.0, but there was no `init.sh` !! So I caanot initialise homestead.. I found a version that contains this file `v2.1.0`. and I used this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead the `Manually Via Git (No Local PHP)` part, but the problem is that the `'laravel/homestead' (v7.1.0)` is the version that is being installed!! I really don't get this! What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Obvious disclaimer: please update to a recent version of PHP and Laravel as soon as possible. You won't get (security) updates for EOL software.

Direct fix: You need Homestead version 6.4 according to [release notes](https://github.com/laravel/settler/releases/tag/v7.0.0). Here is the box: https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.4.0

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I get this error `homestead-7: Failed to restart php5.6-fpm.service: Unit php5.6-fpm.service not found.`  and `homestead-7: Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.` I shouldn't get this error, what do you think?